# Use one USB drive for 3 purposes: OS/recovery installation/data

Tags: ubuntu, boot, partitioning, usb-flash-drive

I have a high performance USB drive and decided to use it for multiple purposes:

1. it should have an OS installed in, like Ubuntu (possibly server version for a lighter weight OS), then when I boot from this drive it can start the OS in it.
2. it should act as a recovery disk, so I can use this one to install a new Ubuntu on other machines: when I start another machine and set to boot from this disk it can let me start installation process.
3. it can be used as a portable data disk so I can copy & paste data: when I plug it in another running machine then that machine can identify the disk (it doesn't matter if there are multiple partitions identified) and let me use the disk to transfer data.

May I stuff all these in one USB drive? Task 1 & 2 seem conflicting, but I was thinking maybe I can partition the disk into 3 partitions, and let each partition for one task only. What should I do to get all three? What file format should the three partitions have? (I would prefer exFat for all, but not sure if that is okay)

Personally, I know what to do for each of the task alone, but feel quite puzzled on how to get all three together. My current tools include: a PC with windows in, a PC with Ubuntu, and a laptop with Mac OS. If the task has to be performed in one of the three major OSes and also some system tools need to be installed, I can install them, too.

UPDATE: if a solution exists that do not require partitioning the disk, that is also fine.

I'm sorry if my question sounds ignorant! But thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, all three tasks can be done on the same USB stick.  You can simply install the Ubuntu OS on the USB stick, that should take care of all three tasks for you.  I personally think using a Live CD on a USB stick is better for what you're looking for.  In order to do that, the first thing you'll need is a program called [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/).  This will allow you to install a Live CD or other bootable .ISO image to the USB drive and use it like you would a burnt disk.  The Live CD should complete tasks 1 & 2 with no problem.  YUMI also has a feature to leave some room on the USB stick for the space you're looking for, which completes task 3.

Edit:  To clarify, YUMI is an installer of sorts that runs on Windows.  When you run it, you'll get the option to install the Live CD onto your USB drive.  It can install a GRUB solution if you so desire, one or more of the distribution options near the bottom should have GRUB listed.  Normally, YUMI will use whatever partition system that's on the drive when you install onto it, (it may need to reformat the drive if you're trying to install a Windows OS).  If your motherboard can read the partition, then it should be able to load the YUMI GUI that will list your options for loading one of the installed systems.  As for the extra storage space, it's supposed to be reserved space that is supposed to be usable on the drive.

Edit 2:  Looks like YUMI creates a file that acts like a small hard drive file that Linux can mount at startup.  Macs probably can as well, but that's not something I have access to.  If push were to come to shove, you could always re-mount the USB drive that the OS is running off of to be re-writable and that should satisfy your third request.  You can read up on how to remount read only filesystems [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175739/how-do-i-remount-a-filesystem-as-read-write).

Comment: This seems like a good solution. I have heard of YUMI, but was originally wanting for a GRUB solution. Anyhow, if YUMI works good enough I'd go for it too. It soulds like following this method I won't need to partition the USB at the very beginning, but just go ahead and install the system on the same USB itself, then log in and use YUMI and take care of all that are left? Would it be an issue if I use exFat for all? Would it be an issue for Windows to identify exchange data partition (later) since it might not be the "first" partition of the device and Windows might not be able to use it?

Comment: I updated my answer to clarify using YUMI.  I won't be able to get to the last part of your question for a while though.

Comment: Many thanks for updating your answer up to this point. It is already quite helpful. I'm using a Mac, though, but I did see there seems YUMI for Mac somewhere online. I'm looking forward to your final update! Meanwhile I'll try this one, too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [easy2boot](http://www.easy2boot.com/)

It requires windows for building the initial image(s), but supports almost any bootable image file. You simply add iso images to the usb drive and select which image you want during the boot process.

It also supports live cd type images with persistent storage (i.e. [winPE based gandalf](http://windowsmatters.com/2015/01/10/gandalfs-windows-7-pe-x86/)). You can also add arbitrary installers, files, etc. to the usb drive.